# How to reverse an animation on mouseLeave

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to implement functionality on a React Card component. onMouseEnter, it triggers a keyframe animation on an image inside of the card. onMouseleave, I want to reverse the keyframe animation instead of having the image just immediately disappear off the screen.

component:

```
export default function Card({ num, title, text }) {
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false)

  return (
    <div 
      onMouseEnter={() => setIsHovered(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovered(false)}
      className='border border-theme h-100 w-96 p-6 flex flex-col justify-between rounded-lg rounded-br-4xl relative'
    >
      <div className='flex justify-between items'>
        <div className='flex flex-col'>
          <span className='text-theme mb-4'>{num}</span>
          <span className='text-paragraph text-3xl w-40'>{title}</span>
        </div>
        <div className='w-12 h-12 rounded-full flex items-center justify-center cursor-pointer overflow-hidden border border-paragraph' >
          <img className="w-8 h-auto" rel="icon" src={arrow} alt="arrow icon" id="test" />
          <div className="arrow-bg"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Image className={`w-28 h-auto self-center rotate-90 opacity-0 ${isHovered && 'test'} transition-all ease-in`} rel="icon" src={cube} alt="cube icon" />
      <p className="text-base">{text}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

CSS:

```
.test {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: cube 1s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes cube {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    transform: rotate(0);
  }


  50% {
    transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: rotate(45deg);

  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    transform: rotate(45deg);

  }
}
```

Comment: Cant you just create a seperate keyframe `@keyframes reverseCube` and hardcode the reverse of `cube` keyframe?

Comment: No can't do that. It's more complicated than that @BuddyBob